# asp.net menu javascript call

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

i have a javascript function that prints out the active grid on a tabcontainer (depending on the active tab)

i can print when i just use a client side call to my print function fine.

instead Now i want to use my asp.net menu and have added a print function.

i want this button press to call my javascript.

The c# code is being called but the javascript just shows that no grid exists yet.

Do  have to call the javascript after the page is fully loaded ? if so how?

thanks
Damo

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function PrintGridData() {
        //var Tab_Name = $(".ajax__tab_active").first().attr('id');
        alert($(".ajax__tab_active").first().attr('id'));
        switch ($(".ajax__tab_active").first().attr('id')) // Switch based on the on active Tab ID
        {
            case 'TabContainerMain_Tab_Monitor_tab':
                var printContent = document.getElementById('<%= GridViewMain.ClientID %>');
                break;
            default:
                alert('Printing not supported');
                return;
        }
        if (printContent)  // See if the Grid Exists First
        {
            if (printContent.rows.length > 0) { // See if the Grid contains any rows

                var windowUrl = 'about:blank';
                var UserLoggedIn = $("#lblUser").text()
                var now = new Date();
                var strDateTime = [[AddZero(now.getDate()), AddZero(now.getMonth() + 1), now.getFullYear()].join("/"), [AddZero(now.getHours()), AddZero(now.getMinutes())].join(":"), now.getHours() >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM"].join(" ");
                var windowName = 'Report';
                var AuditPrintDetail = 'Report ' + UserLoggedIn + " " + strDateTime;
                var WinPrint = window.open(windowUrl, windowName, 'left=300,top=300,right=500,bottom=500,width=1000,height=500');
                WinPrint.document.write('<' + 'html' + '><head><link href="assets/css/Main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />     <title>' + AuditPrintDetail + '</title> </head><' + 'body  style="background:none !important"' + '>');
                WinPrint.document.write(printContent.outerHTML);
                WinPrint.document.write('<' + '/body' + '><' + '/html' + '>');
                WinPrint.document.close();
                WinPrint.focus();
                WinPrint.print();
                WinPrint.close();
            }
            else {alert("No Results to print!");}
        }
        else {alert("No Grid to print!");}
    }

    function AddZero(num) {return (num >= 0 && num < 10) ? "0" + num : num + "";}
</script>
```

**Markup**

```
<div id="DivMenu">
                    <asp:Menu CssClass="Menu" ID="MenuMain" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" OnMenuItemClick="MenuMain_MenuItemClick">
                        <Items>
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="System" Value="System">
                                <asp:MenuItem Text="Logout" Value="Logout"></asp:MenuItem>
                                <asp:MenuItem Text="Print" Value="Print"></asp:MenuItem>
                            </asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="Help" Value="Help">
                                <asp:MenuItem Text="About" Value="About"></asp:MenuItem>
                            </asp:MenuItem>
                        </Items>
                        <StaticHoverStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" />
                        <StaticMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
                        <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="White" />
                    </asp:Menu>
                </div>
```

**C#**

```
  protected void MenuMain_MenuItemClick(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
        {

                if (e.Item.Text == "About")
                {
                    AboutModal.Show();


                }


                if (e.Item.Text == "Logout")
                {
                    //Log the user out

                    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                    FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
                }


                if (e.Item.Text == "Print")
                {


                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), "JsStatus", "PrintGridData();", true);


                }
            }
```

Comment: Are you getting any error in javascript? Please try FireBug or similar things to see what is the exact error. Is printContent gets any data at all?

Comment: it gets nothing at all, im pretty sure that possibly the page hasnt loaded yet and that is the issue but i dont know. cal i call a clientside function from an asp.net menu?

Comment: Yes, you can call javascript function from asp.net menu. if the page is not loaded yet, you will get script error. Are you getting any script error?

Comment: Not getting an error. My function just runs and says that the grid has no data which is what would happen when it isn't rendered yet. When the alert is displayed I can see that the grid is not there. After I acknowledge the error the grid and the rest of the page is drawn

Comment: Could you please try this and see if it make any difference 
var printContent = $('#<%= GridViewMain.ClientID %>').html();

Comment: hi, that didnt work either - same error - im going to put a button print on the relevant tab pages and just use all client side code. Pity it didnt work but thanks for the help